# How to Get state of NSButton (CheckBox) from NSMatrix

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsbuttoncell

Why my code changes the state of selected `NSButtenCell` to `NSOnState` after first run?

```
NSButtonCell *b=[[NSButtonCell alloc] init];
b=[self.myMatrix selectedCell];
[self.myMatrix selectCellAtRow:0 column:0];
if (b.state == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"State is On");
}else{
    NSLog(@"State is Off");
}
```

What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but did you check whether calling

```
[self.myMatrix selectCellAtRow:0 column:0];
```

performs the state change?

The Apple documentation for NSMatrix says:

*> If the specified cell is an editable text cell, its text is selected.*

So perhaps this method also may change the checkbox state (but I don't know if that may be the issue).